# get a point from characterIndex in wpf textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Im using a custom caret in a WPF textbox, I want to get the Point(x,y) from the characterIndex or the caretIndex. There is a way to convert a point(x,y) to a characterIndex (getCharacterIndexfromPoint) but is there a way to do the other way round?

Comment: But why the **getCharacterIndexfromPoint** is not suitable for you? Maybe there is a problem with your code?

Comment: I solved it thanks! I want to set the position of the customcaret, which doesnt know where the CaretIndex of the textbox is, so the only way to set the customCaret is to know the pixel position of the CaretIndex, whichis this way: getRectFromCharaterIndex().